# What is the proper way of using two traits mutually

Tags: php, oop

Recently, I have faced an error, and after very long debugging, it turned out using two traits mutually caused the error.

For example:

```
namespace App\Traits;

use App\Traits\Transactions;

trait Reports
{
   use Transactions;
}
```

```
namespace App\Traits;

use App\Traits\Reports;

trait Transactions
{
   use Reports;
}
```

In my case, I got the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Trait "App\Traits\Transactions" not found

File: App\Trais\Reports
```

What is the way of using traits mutually?

Comment: Speling mistake in your filename? App\Trais\Reports

Comment: Also you don't need the `use` statements if the traits are part of the same `namespace`

Comment: Having traits depending on each other looks like a design problem, try and work out what you are trying to do with them and see if there is a more logical solution.

Comment: @gskema I did't copy and paste them, so typo is here only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to use `trait Transactions` using `trait Reports` using `trait Transactions` using `trait Reports` using `trait Transactions` using...

That loop leads to Error that `trait Reports` cannot load `trait Transactions`, so you have an error. You cannot do that like this.

First, you need to consider why u need trait A using B using A...

Like you could see in that thinking `trait A` is exactly `trait B` and vice verse (Because trait A using B, and B using A) even if they both have others methods, let's say `trait A` have `A::A()` method, and `B` have `B::B()` method, so if they using thyself they both have `A()` and `B()` methods so you don't need two traits, because it's exactly the same.

But you could want sometimes using only `A()` method and otherwise only `B()` method, so u could separate this like:

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait AB
{
    use A, B;
}

trait A
{
   function a() {}
}

trait B
{
   function b() {}
}
```

also you don't need the `use` statements if the traits are part of the same `namespace`

Comment: If I do something related to Report, it hits ReportController, which uses ReportTrait, which needs a function from TransactionTrait. If I do something related to Transaction, it hits TransactionController, which uses TransactionTrait, which needs a function from ReportTrait.

Comment: It's not possible to use Trait A using Trait B using Trait C ... using Trait Z which is using again Trait A, because then trait B would never be loaded. (https://3v4l.org/VBnT8)